# Trying to get property of non-object - database row doesnt exist

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter and getting the following error: Trying to get property of non-object. I'm 100% sure that its because the query is not finding an existing row in the database because when it does it works fine. I'm new to CodeIgniter though and not sure how to fix this?

Here is the function in my model

```
function getSent(){

    $this->db->where('submit_time', $this->uri->segment(3));
    $tempsent = $this->db->get('0_request_details');  //this is the problem here. If it doesnt find the row from the database above it doesnt know what to do here

    if($tempsent){

        $data['sent'] = $tempsent->row();

    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: get('0_request_details')

Comment: are you doing pagination ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, adding an IF

```
function getSent()
{
    $this->db->where('submit_time', $this->uri->segment(3));
    $tempsent = $this->db->get('0_request_details');
    if ( $tempsent->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
        // If a row is found...
        $data['sent'] = $tempsent->row();
        return $data;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one... :)

```
$this->db->select('field_1 , field_2');
$this->db->where('field_name' , $this->uri->segment(3));
$tempsent = $this->db->get('table_name');

$data = (object) NULL;

if($tempsent->num_rows() > 0)
{
    $data->sent = $info->result();
}

return $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

here are some suggestions --

- is your database table really called '0_request_details' ???
  having a number starting a database table name could be a problem.
  for this example i'll call it 'request_details'
- check and confirm the value in $this->uri->segment(3) first. if its blank or malformed you want to know. and you don't want to submit it to the database - you want a clear error letting you know the issue.
- don't attach the database result to $data in your model. do that in your controller. for more complicated tasks you will have multiple arrays/objects going to $data - you want to be able to see that clearly in your controller.
- don't forget to state the database table fields you want returned.

in controller

```
   // example your model is called request 
   // check if we got a submit_time back
   // if we don't get a submit_time back then its invalid
   if ( ! $submit_time =  $this->request->returnValidatedSubmitTime ) {

       $this->showInvalidSubmitTime($submit_time) ; } 

   // $submit_time is valid, now try to get a database record
   // check if we got a record back
   elseif( ! $data['sent'] = $this->request->getSentWith($submit_time) ) {

       $this->showNoRecordsFor($submit_time) ;  }

   else {

      // Success 
      // $data['sent'] has been set and available to views    
   }
```

in model

```
    function returnValidatedSubmitTime(){       

    if($this->uri->segment(3) ) {

     $time = $this->uri->segment(3) ; 

     // do some validation 

    // if its valid 

     return $time; 

    } 
    else { return false ; } 

  } 

    function getSentWith($submit_time){

        // the fields that will be returned     
        $this->db->select( 'id, firstname, lastname' );
        $this->db->where('submit_time', $submit_time);
        $query = $this->db->get('request_details'); 

        // we are only expecting one row so thats what we check for       
            if ( $query->num_rows() == 1 ) {

              return $query->row(); }

             else
            // no results 
            { return FALSE; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your Code

```
function getSent(){

$this->db->where('submit_time', $this->uri->segment(3));
$tempsent = $this->db->get('0_request_details');  //this is the problem here. If it doesnt find the     row from the database above it doesnt know what to do here

if($tempsent){

    $data['sent'] = $tempsent->row();

}

return $data;
}
```

what you have to do is to drag the array result like; you can do it in two ways

```
function getSent(){

$this->db->where('submit_time', $this->uri->segment(3));
$tempsent = $this->db->get('0_request_details');  //this is the problem here. If it doesnt find the     row from the database above it doesnt know what to do here

if($tempsent){
foreach($tempsent->result() as $ts)
{
$data['sent']=$ts;
}

}

return $data;
}
```

secondly you can append ->result() at the end of your query to get the result that point and later on use the output as an array index.

hope somehow you got the idea